# Google App Engine Python - Using the Datastore

Tags: python, google-app-engine

I have manually typed code mentioned @
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore
in helloworld.py

I've the dev_appserver.py server running, and visiting localhost:8080 doesn't show anything.

If I insert a debug messages as seen @ http://pastebin.com/VtCMjrk8

I see the output below @ localhost:8080
**"Greeting(db.Model) Start main function() MainPage class guestbook_key function Status: 200 OK Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8 Cache-Control: no-cache Expires: Fri, 01 Jan 1990 00:00:00 GMT Content-Length: 12 "**

I'm on Windows Vista Basic 32-bit.

UPDATE:
I can't believe this.
If I copy paste the code from https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingdatastore
in helloworld.py,  I do see the desired output.

What could be the issue ?

## 2)

Also,
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingusers
The output @ localhost:8080  shows the hello +   instead of allowing me to pick or enter a username

What could be the reason ?

Comment: What is your question? If you use the code it doesn't work, but if you use the same code it works? What do you mean?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for the response. I have modified the question. Is it clear now?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Thanks for asking. Problem's solved :) I have the answer in the last comment to answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably typed something wrong.  Use a debugger and step through the code to figure out what's not working.

Comment: Ok. What about the second question ?

Comment: You posted a link, but you obviously didn't read it.  There's nothing in your code that allows the user to login.  I don't see create_login_url() anywhere in your code.

Comment: The link clearly says 
**Reload the page in your browser. Your application redirects you to the local version of the Google sign-in page suitable for testing your application. You can enter any username you'd like in this screen, and your application will see a fake User object based on that username.**
Stop assuming People don't read what they post.
Not everybody is a lazy person. I hope you understand that some day.

Comment: Yes, but the code on that page is not the same as the code in your pastebin.

Comment: Except for print statements on code in pastebin, both are same

Comment: there's no create_login_url() in your pastebin/usingdatastore code.  the login is in the usingusers code, which you don't have.

Comment: Oh sorry, the pastebin code is for the using datastore issue.
Sorry for the confusion. Let us put it aside
 
What I mean is the code I used for getting the desired output for usingusers section is the same as code @ 
https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/usingusers
The received output shows only Hello and <username> but not a local version of google sign-in page. 
Could it be that I already signed in even before trying the "using the users code" which's why I don't see local version of google  sign-in page?

Comment: While I don't think everyone is a lazy person, I get the clear sense that you've been too lazy to step through this using a debugger.  It should become clear enough what the problem is when you do that.

Comment: The reason why I have not used a debugger is because it's an example that I just expected it to work because I have not modified anything.
I copy pasted the code exactly as mentioned. I don't understand why I would need a debugger for situations like this. Is it not possible to just look at the code and tell the issue for a simple example like this ?

Comment: problem solved. in the using the users code, first time i logged in, there was no logout sign. so i coud not see the re-direct page. but the code @ https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/gettingstarted/templates has a create_logout_url line of code. thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

The answer to the original question of why the hand typed code didn't work while the cut paste code worked is that the last statement in class `MainPage` (shown below), needs to be indented at the For level (so it will be out of the For loop). In Python the indentation matters a lot!!

```
self.response.out.write("""  .......
```

Comment: Indeed. I overlooked that then before posting the question. Thanks!